# I need to make Update clause when 3 row have the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to make  Update clause when 3 row or any number of row have the same value

```
DECLARE @Tbl_1 TABLE (Id int,ParentID int,State nvarchar(50) )
DECLARE @Tbl_2 TABLE (Id int,ParentID int,State nvarchar(50) )


INSERT INTO @Tbl_1 VALUES 
(1,10,'New')



INSERT INTO @Tbl_2 VALUES 
 (1,1,'New')
,(2,1,'New')
,(3,1,'New')

SELECT * FROM @Tbl_1
Id  ParentID    State
1   10          New

SELECT * FROM @Tbl_2
Id  ParentID    State
1   1           New
2   1           New
3   1           New
```

what i need to set the @Tbl_1.State = 'Deducted'

when all the matched row in @Tbl_2.State = 'Deducted'

If @tbl_2.State Look Like This

```
Id  ParentID    State
1   10          Deducted
1   10          Deducted
1   10          New
```

i need the @tbl_1.State = 'New' i dont need to make update becouse the all matched row did't = 'Deducted'

But if the all Matched row = 'Deducted'
then 
i make a update

and the final data should look like this 
@tbl_1

```
Id  ParentID    State
1   10          Deducted
```

@tbl_2

```
Id  ParentID    State
1   10          Deducted
1   10          Deducted
1   10          Deducted
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update t
set State = 'Deducted'
FROM @Tbl_1 t
where 'Deducted' = all (select State from @Tbl_2 t2 where ParentID = t.Id)
```

How keyword all works is explained there: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/where-any-all

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
update t1
    set state = 'Deducted'
    from @tbl_1 t1
    where not exists (select 1
                      from @tbl_2 t2
                      where t2.state <> 'Deducted' and t2.id = t1.id
                     );
```

This interprets "when all the matched row in @Tbl_2.State = 'Deducted'" as meaning that it should be `'Deducted'` even when there are no rows in `@tbl_2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an update join like this:

```
update t1
set state = 'Deducted'
from @tbl_1 t1
join (
    select ParentID
    from @tbl_2
    group by ParentID
    having max(state) = min(state)
        and min(state) = 'Deducted'
    ) t2 on t1.id = t2.ParentID;
```

It will update all those rows in tbl_1 to Deducted which have all the rows set to deducted in tbl_2. It will not update the rows if there is not corresponding row in tbl_2, which I assume is as per desired.

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/JTFQK62966)